# How to receive Apple Push Notification on Android mobile? How to install IOS in Android?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Can i install IOS on my Android mobile to receive Apple push notification?. If yes how to install IOS on my Android mobile and how to receive push notification?

Comment: To be frank, it not possible to install apple iOS on android mobile/tablet. This method is completely about How To Convert Android Phone to iPhone. I think you got my point. Yes, you can change your phone’s user interface as in iOS devices. But the in built Operating system on your device remains android only.

Comment: I need to install ios in my android mobile

Comment: You cannot install iOS in your "android mobile".

Comment: But can i convert my device os  as iOS ?

Comment: Downvoter : may i knw y its downvoted?

Comment: I hope that, after almost two years, you understand why this is a bad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i install IOS on my Android mobile to receive Apple push
> notification?.  Not Possible at all. IOS is more secured and confined
> in own way.

```
how to receive push notification ?
or How to receive IOS push notification on android ?
```

ANS : [image]

you need to build android app, configure GCM for it. Provider is your server which is generating push notifications (ios) or cloud messages ( android ) to  mobiles. All you need to do is add one more call to GCM to get push notification in andoid app.

> Can i convert my android os into iOS. Like installing linux and
> windows on same laptop. Because in mobile also we have
> processor,ram,rom. So y we can't install an iOS in Mobile device?

Yes. Very true. Device are same when comes to hardware, but its more specific on software part not hardware part. IOS is more secured and confined means it has its own constraints that need to fullfilled. And more IPHONE has no mutiple vendors, but android does.

Comment: Can i convert my android os into iOS. Like installing linux and windows on same laptop. Because in mobile also we have processor,ram,rom. So y we can't install an iOS in Mobile device?

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have to root your device if you want to install iOS to Android Smartphone. Just download the software, which is found on the “Sources” section of this page, in your PC. Then, connect  your Smartphone to your computer. Open the downloaded program and follow the step-by-step procedures there.

Comment: can u provide any link ?